# Zend Framework 2 DI alias, same controller name in different modules

Tags: zend-framework2

I have an application with 3 modules and route configs like below:

- admin.domain.tld/[:controller[:/action]] => Admin
- rest.domain.tld/[:controller[:/id]] => Rest
- domain.tld/[:controller[:/action]] => Site

and set DI alias for all controller in each modules

REST Module DI Alias:

```
'alias' => array(
    'index' => 'Rest\Controller\IndexController',
    ...
),
```

Admin Module DI Alias:

```
'alias' => array(
    'index' => 'Admin\Controller\IndexController',
    ...
),
```

Site Module DI Alias:

```
'alias' => array(
    'index' => 'Site\Controller\IndexController',
    ...
),
```

As you see, some controllers has same name (eg: `IndexController`), but since zf2 merged config with LIFO behaviour, 'index' alias always from the last added module.

Application Config

```
'modules' => array('Rest','Admin', 'Site'),
```

when i access http://admin.domain.tld/ I expect `index` alias gives `Admin\Controller\IndexController` but since Site Module (registered last) has same alias for `index` it gives  `Site\Controller\IndexController`

How to use different DI alias to match same controller name?

Comment: May you post some of your configs/DI?

Comment: I update the question to show you DI alias configurations for each module and application modules config registration.

Comment: See the configs from Akrabat website: http://akrabat.com/zend-framework-2/overriding-module-configuration-in-zf2/ he generate routers for each module, not alias.

Comment: @Gabriel thanks, what i want to achieve here is using catchall routing instead of add individual route for each controller, but according to Matthew, they working on `per-module solutions` until then the best solutions is using specific router for each

Comment: Akrabat do a per-module work..

Comment: @Gabriel true, but with specific routing for each controller, not the catchall routing as i stated here, its exactly like `Jurian` answer down below.

Answer (score 3):

Before the new view layer was merged into master, it was required to have aliases for controllers to behave correctly when resolving view scripts. Now this is not required anymore, it is even not recommended anymore to use aliases for controllers. The problem with aliasing is there is one alias for one FQCN, so your problem is directly related to this.

What you need to do is to remove aliases from the DI configuration and use explicit routes instead. The "magic" route [:controller[/:action]] is a bad practice and results in more problems than it can help you. So write some explicit routes and remove the aliases.

Comment: thanks for your response, somehow I like more the approach above, which is running pretty well within current app with zf1, here i simply want to convert it to zf2. Each modules has many controllers and i dont want to write bunches of routing configurations for each of them. I think would be good if DI support module isolated configiration or even prefix aliasing

Comment: @Komang I just wrote down what is recommended and the suggested way. There is not yet a "magic" route, but there will be one which covers your use case. You can get collisions in route names and this will not be the fastest method, but it might be easy for RAD processes. You can also still use segmented routes with optional segments for actions and other parameters, you don't need to fully specify all route points. For controllers though, don't use aliases if you want to keep your apps modular.

Comment: thanks again, Matthew also suggesting the same approach, so no other clue to keep catchall routing :/controller in this case. ~ "there will be one which covers your use case" ~ is there a proposal for that?

Comment: @Komang there is no proposal for, but a story on the AgileZen board: https://agilezen.com/project/33552/story/24. You can track changes there. If you do not have an account for agilezen.com yet, you can also view the overview on http://framework.zend.com/zf2/board